# Splitting url by nth characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that is getting too much traffic and I want to cache some of the pages, which should alleviate the problem.

I have a system for this in place already, but the issue is the url structure would lead to 11.365 million pages being saved in one directory, e.g.

dir/* <- 11+ million pages saved in this directory.

And this will make things very difficult when it comes to deleting the directory.

Via a predictive search I am using JavaScript to split down the cache like:

```
people/joh/n-j/one/s.json
```

Which is more manageable to delete.

Is there anyway I can use mod_rewrite to split urls down in the same way, e.g.

1. User loads `/people/john-jones`
2. Use mod_rewrite to see if `caches/html/people/joh/n-j/one/s.html` exists, if so server it
3. Else go to PHP an generate the page

I have a rule for this already, but not with splitting:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^(.+)\/cache [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=PATH:%1]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+ %{ENV:PATH}/index.php?request=a&c=search&m=people&p=$0 [L]
```

Comment: What if the name has exactly a multiple of n characters?

Comment: In my caching of predictive search into json files, it woks like this: 1) A query for "a" results in /cache/a.json; "an" => /cache/an.json; "and" => /cache/and.json; "andr" => /cache/and/r.json ... and so on. I'd like the same done though mod_rewrite, but I think it is not possible, it would have to be routed through PHP to split the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following rules a try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(people/.*?)([^/]{3})([^/]+)$ /$1$2/$3 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/caches/html%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/caches/html%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

---

The suggested edit by OP was rejected in [peer review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10197151). Here's the solution OP went with:

```
# Set an environmental var for the root directory, so it works on local dev and live servers

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^(.+)\/index.php$    [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=PATH:%1]

# Pick up the actual request from query string and set it as an environmental var

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^request=names\/(.*?)([^/]{3})([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=SN:%1%2/%3]

# If a cache paged exists, internal redirect to that

RewriteCond %{ENV:PATH}/cache/html/names/%{ENV:SN}.html -f
RewriteRule .* cache/html/names/%{ENV:SN}.html [L]

# Send requests that are not cached to php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php?request=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This isn't the exact type of splitting I initially wanted, but after some thought I think it would actually be better. I've edited and added the code that worked in my specific example.